# Unable to catch Error: The Following Error occured: list index out of range

Tags: exception, error-handling

```
def ok():
    global name
    name=str(entryname.get())
    try:
        meaning=str(dictionary.meaning(name))
    except:
        print "Word not recognized"
```

I am a newbie and the above code keeps giving an error which I would like to catch.

The error occurs when name is a random word like "sdhgshgf". The dictionary does return "None", and I've also checked the length as 4. 
Any help would be appreciated! Note I've already tried `except (IndexError, ValueError)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well since the error only occurs when the entry isn't a real word, I used [PyEnchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) to first check if the word is real before trying to get a definition. No idea if you still need this but I just encountered a similar problem and felt like answering.

```
>>>import enchant
>>>wordCheck = enchant.Dict("en_US")
>>>wordCheck.check("Flower")
True
>>>wordCheck.check("sdfl;kjsdflkjsdfl")
False
```